# install from github using composer and no composer.json in github

Tags: cakephp, github, composer-php

I try to install the plugin CakePHP-CSV using Composer. I forked it from ProLoser/CakePHP-CSV.
I don't want to install it in Vendor, but in Plugin folder and with the name of Csv and not the default one that is the plugin name. I tried to use the extra in composer.json but what ever I tried it installs it in Vendor folder of the project.

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "CakePHP-CSV/Csv",
            "version": "dev-master",
            "source": {
                "url": "https://github.com/sela/CakePHP-CSV",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "origin/master"
            }
        }
    }
],
"require": {
    "CakePHP-CSV/Csv": "dev-master",
},
"config": {
    "vendor-dir": "Vendor"
},
"extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
        "Plugin/Cvs": ["Plugin/cvs"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your package depend on [`composer/installers`](https://github.com/composer/installers).

From [Composer's documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-do-i-install-a-package-to-a-custom-path-for-my-framework.md):

> If you are a **package author** and want your package installed to a custom directory, simply require `composer/installers` and set the appropriate `type`. This is common if your package is intended for a specific framework such as CakePHP, Drupal or WordPress. Here is an example composer.json file for a WordPress theme:
>
> ```
> {
>     "name": "you/themename",
>     "type": "wordpress-theme",
>     "require": {
>         "composer/installers": "~1.0"
>     }
> }
> ```

And later (I've added italics to the important part):

> As a **package consumer** you can set or override the install path *for a package that requires composer/installers* by configuring the `installer-paths` extra. A useful example would be for a Drupal multisite setup where the package should be installed into your sites subdirectory.

Note that [`extra` is simply a place to put arbitrary data](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#extra):

> Arbitrary extra data for consumption by `scripts`.
>
> This can be virtually anything. To access it from within a script event handler, you can do:
>
> ```
> $extra = $event->getComposer()->getPackage()->getExtra();
> ```

The second part is very important; something has to *retrieve the extra data and do something with it*. In this instance that something is `composer/installers`.

Comment: thanks. first you copied the example composer.json where do I need to put the composer.json? I fork the code to my own repository, but is there a way to do it if I don't fork it and create composer.json to the plugin?
I got 1 composer.json already on my local machine.

Comment: @SelaYair, there are two relevant `composer.json` files. The first is for *the package*, and this one must require `composer/installers`. Normally the package author would provide this, but this particular library doesn't seem to do that so you may have to create it yourself. Forking the repository is a good way to do that, though you'll be responsible for merging upstream changes into your fork.

Comment: The other `composer.json` is the one for *your application*, which depends on the CSV library and whatever other libraries you need. This is where you'll put the `extra` / `installer-paths` bit to relocate the CSV library.

Comment: Note that there is lots of documentation for creating Composer packages, as well as for `composer/installers`. You should read that; you may need to make other changes to the upstream library to get it to play nice.

Answer (score 0):

I needed more space for the code so I answer myself. The following code worked and I didn't need to fork the code.

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "ProLoser/CakePHP-CSV",
            "version": "1.0",
            "type": "cakephp-plugin",
            "dist": {
                "url": "https://github.com/ProLoser/CakePHP-CSV/archive/master.zip",
                "type": "zip"
            }
        }
    }
],
"require": {
    "composer/installers": "~1.0.0",
    "ProLoser/CakePHP-CSV": "1.*"
},
"config": {
    "vendor-dir": "Vendor"
}
```